# Проверка наличия виджета во Фрейме

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет, пишу небольшую программку с интерфейсом на Tkinter и столкнулся со сложностью.

Условно, при вызове функции (клике по значениям во Frame А), условные параметры передаются в соседний фрейм (Frame B) и визуализируются, каждый раз обновляясь в виджете Entry.

В зависимости от значения переданного параметра (например "OMS"), необходимо предоставить возможность выбора выполнить еще какую-то операцию (функцию), и для этого отрисовывается кнопка ("Do Smt").
Но после выбора следующего значения кнопка остается "висеть" во фрейме В.

Подскажите можно ли как-то реализовать проверку в функции user_choice наличия кнопки во Фрейме В и удаления ее.
Понимаю, что можно перед каждым вызовом user_choice() удалять все виджеты Frame B и отрисовывать их заново, но данное решение кажется костылем, хочется найти более деликатное решение

Код примера:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class main_interface():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("20x450")
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        entry = ttk.Entry(self.window, width=30)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)

        frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, text="Frame A", relief=tk.RIDGE, width=200, height=200)
        frame1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)

        frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, text="Frame B", relief=tk.RIDGE, width=200, height=200)
        frame2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S)

        entry = ttk.Entry(frame2, width=30)
        entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.W, pady=3)

        request = {"NSK": "9383XXXX",
                   "OMS": "9381XXXX",
                   "TMN": "9345XXXX",
                   "KZN": "9843XXXX",
                   "NNV": "9831XXXX"}

        for row, (key, value) in enumerate(request.items()):
            formated_text = " {} - {}".format(key, value)
            found_result_label = ttk.Label(frame1, text=formated_text)

            selected_string = key, value
            found_result_label.bind("<Button-1>", func=lambda event, text=selected_string: user_choice(text))
            found_result_label.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        def user_choice(text):

            entry.delete(0, "end")
            entry.insert(0, text)

            if text[0] == "OMS":
                button = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Do Smt", command=lambda: fx())
                button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)

        def fx():
            pass

program = main_interface()
program.window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно записывать кнопку в поле объекта, при необходимости ее удалять

```
    self.button = None

    def user_choice(text):

        entry.delete(0, "end")
        entry.insert(0, text)

        if self.button:  # Если кнопка уже существует -
            self.button.destroy()  # уничтожить!!!
            self.button = None

        if text[0] == "OMS":
            self.button = ttk.Button(frame2, text="Do Smt", command=lambda: fx())
            self.button.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.W)
```

Comment: Спасибо за интересное решение, а не подскажете такой ньюанс в Вашем решении: предположим кнопка должна появляться при выборе 2-х параметров (например: if text[0] == "OMS" or text[0] == "NNV":), тогда тоже все работает, но только до тех пор, пока не выбрать оба подходящих параметра подряд. Поясню: выбираем "OMS" - появляется кнопка, выбираем "NNV" - кнопка остается, дальше уже не важно, что выбирать - кнопка останется при сочетании любых комбинаций. Баг или Фича, почему так получается ?

Comment: Да, баг. В этом случае старая кнопка не удаляется, а поверх неё создаётся новая. Как доберусь до компьютера, обновлю ответ.

Comment: @Luarvick, поправил, просто нужно уничтожать кнопку (если она существует) при входе в функцию.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь